# Ionic 2 alert in array

Tags: ionic2

how do i display this error in ionic 2 alert ?

example error messages :

```
{
  "name": [
    "The name field is required."
  ],
  "email": [
    "The email field is required."
  ],
  "password": [
    "The password field is required."
  ]
}
```

Comment: you need to show what you have tried.. read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please give us the example... btw maybe with `"name":"The name field is required."` try but i dont know if this will work cause i dont know what are you doing

Comment: Just a tip: It's better for you to use inline validation for this. It's bad UX to throw lots of alerts on the user's face, like if he forgets the email and password and click on the button. Try using a <p> tag that shows only when the input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

---

Edit: You also need to import the AlertController of course:

```
Import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

---

I modified the example given in the [Ionic 2 documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

```
constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

}

funTest(){
    let test={"name":['The name field is required']};

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Error",
      message: test.name.toString(),
      buttons: ["OK"]
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

By the way, why do you use arrays? If you just use:

```
{"name":"The name field is required"}
```

you won't even need the .toString().

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use `AlertController` for that, but it seems you are validating inputs..for that its better to use `Forms` where you can validate easily..
check this out , hope it can help: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/forms/